# What is vector potential in magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic

The vector potential in magnetic field (represented by A), what does that physically mean? I have serious problem in understanding it intuitively.

$$\nabla^2\text{A} = -\mu_0 \text{j}$$

I read that the above equation can be derived using continuity equation. Can it be derived? if possible how? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is the vector potential is such that the curl of it gives the B field.  (Taking a curl is often easier than integrating.)  There is also a fascinating quantum mechanical effect, such that the vector potential leads to a phase change of particles.  I went looking on line and it's hard to beat the Feynman lectures.  [Enjoy!](http://feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_15.html)

Comment: I read through the whole lectures of feynman found it really helpful and got to know about the derivation too.thank u